# bash: if equivalent of case statement

Tags: bash

I'm a bit confused about the case statement in Bash vs other languages.  Perhaps it's best asked by a direct question.  What's the if-statement equivalent of:

```
   case $filename in
       *_[0-9][0-9] )
          echo "fine";;
       *)
          echo "fail";;
   esac
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that whereas the `case` version is POSIX-compliant, the below is specific to shells, such as bash, which adopt ksh extensions. (POSIX sh doesn't provide any native mechanism other than `case` to perform fnmatch-style pattern matching against variable contents rather than the filesystem).

```
if [[ $filename = *_[0-9][0-9] ]]; then
      echo "fine"
else
      echo "fail"
fi
```

See [BashFAQ #31](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) for more on `[[` and how it differs from the built-in `[` and `test` commands.

Also see [the POSIX sh specification for `case`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_04_05).

Comment: Thanks.  Do I ever want to use double quotes with the [[ ]] then?

Comment: Double quotes on the left-hand side of `[[ $foo = $bar ]]` are strictly optional. On the right-hand side, they make contents literal -- an exact substring match rather than a glob-style pattern match.

Comment: (One of the key distinctions between `[[ ]]` and `[ ]` is that the former is shell syntax, whereas the latter is just a built-in command and uses the same parsing rules as everything else, including commands external to the shell; it's only being syntax that allows `[[ ]]` to suppress glob expansion and string-splitting on expansions, to allow the code being run to *know* character-by-character how its arguments were quoted, and the like).